# Программный переход на предыдущий UIViewController

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Был произведён переход из одного Controller'a на другой через Push, а как программно вернуться на предыдущий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```